# keystore getEntry returns null second time

Tags: java, security, keystore, private-key

In my request doPost I have the following code.

```
        File file = new File("C:\\temp\\HelloWorld.P12");
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        String password = "helloworld";
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)
                keystore.getEntry("hello", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("helloworld".toCharArray()));
```

For the first request `pkEntry` returns NOT NULL value and I am able to get private key.  But second time it returns NULL so I am unable to get private key from second request onwards.  What do I need to do to get `pkEntry` NOT NULL for every request?

Comment: Looks like I have to call KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); only once

Comment: also I should not call keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
second time

Answer (score 0):

Load certificate code into the static block inside, loaded only once.